# What is the function to get the quotient and remainder (DIVMOD) for rust?

Tags: rust, division, modulo

x86 and likely other architectures provide a method to get the quotient and remainder in a [single operation (`DIV`)](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/div). Because of this many languages have a DIVMOD combined operation, (like [`DIVREM` in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.divrem?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Math_DivRem_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32__), [`DIVMOD` in Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_divmod.asp), or with [`div` and `div_t` in C](https://linux.die.net/man/3/div). How can I do this in Rust?

Is there an optimized method to perform both

```rust
let res = (a / b, a % b);
```

Comment: I think modern compilers such as LLVM are able to guess that you are doing the same division and module and optimize both operation to a single operation, such as in this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=95c25b479730f221a5a5283ad3e2a664).

Comment: I would also like this, not as a performance optimization, but because it breaks my brain to see a single semantic operation expressed twice, as two similar yet subtly different expressions, in code.  For example, the checked_div() and checked_rem() calls in [Bevy's Timer::tick()](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/blob/main/crates/bevy_time/src/timer.rs#L227-L236) method seem like they should be a single expression that evaluates to a (div, rem) pair.

Answer (score 11):

As rodrigo commented already, the compiler is able to optimize this away. For the sake of completeness, there is a [num_integer::div_rem](https://docs.rs/num-integer/0.1.44/num_integer/fn.div_rem.html) method if you need it for generic integer types, but I'd vote against using this library if you don't need to be generic